# How to view dataframe columns based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

[image]

For the above example,
I want to have a look at the value of `outlet_size` when `Outlet_identifier = OUT049` or any value for that instance.
I don't want to produce a new dataframe object and then print it, instead I want to know if there is any function or way to directly view it.

Comment: `df.loc[df['Outlet_identifier'] == 'OUT049']`?

Comment: have you tried `loc` `df.loc[df['Outlet_identifier'].eq('OUT049'), 'outlet_size']`

Comment: Have you read [the pandas documentation for indexing, filtering, and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)? What have you tried and what were your results?

Comment: @QuangHoang This returns the entire dataframe with all the columns. I need only the `Outlet_Identifier` and `Outlet_Size` column to be shown

Comment: @Kenan Great. It was something new to me. But still, it does not serve the motive. It returns a series while I need both the columns to be shown for comparison.

Comment: @AmitPathak commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both columns

`df.loc[df['Outlet_identifier'].eq('OUT049'), ['Outlet_identifier', 'outlet_size']]`

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with pandas like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Outlet_identifier': ['OUT049','OUT018','OUT049'], 'outlet_size': 
[2.0, 2.0, 2.0]})
df[df["Outlet_identifier"]=="OUT049"]["outlet_size"]
```

Comment: I tried. This returns a series with 'Outlet_Size' column. I need both to be shown.